# Sound through only left speaker, (but hardware is OK)

Tags: ubuntu, audio, pulseaudio

I have *Ubuntu 19.04*, and I am facing issues with sounds. When playing audio, I get audio through only one of the speakers (the left one, that is). Also, the volume is pretty low. I run the same on windows 10 (through dual boot), and both speakers run perfectly fine with proper amplification. What should I do?

Comment: Do you use GUI? If so, run `pavucontrol` and investigate. Especially Playback, Output Devices and Configuraton tabs. Screenshots of these tabs may be helpful. I believe Pulse Audio can also be configured via command line, so don't be surprised if somebody tries to guide you this way.

Comment: I am facing same problem. I have Win10 on dual boot as well and it works in Win10. I haven't found solution yet. Have you found anything?

Answer (score 0):

Open up `alsamixer`, and check out channels, and play around with the inputs. I have a Focusrite Scarlett 6i6, and was only getting my left channel coming through both speakers. Like you - my volume was also very lacking as well. For me; my outputs were incorrectly labelled as headphone outputs. Changing `Master 2R (Headphone) Source` from `PCM 1` (right channel) to `PCM 2` (left channel) worked.

Comment: QaSMixer is a good gui for the AlsaMixer, since I found the terminal interface required a lot of scrolling to see all the settings in one glance. Looks like I can even change the inputs from Hi-Z to Low-Z, and other features.